# setTimeout and jQuery UI-Draggable/Droppable expand list on hover

Tags: jquery-ui, settimeout, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

JSFiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/bkfxjnom/4/

I'm having trouble getting setTimeout to work correctly with droppable.over. It only seems to fire off the function randomly when moving from one droppable to the other. While if I exit the droppable area, and move back to another droppable, then it appears to work as intended. I'm assuming there is some conflict between the over and out events when moving between droppables. Any help with a fix is appreciated.

```
var globalTimer;
$('li.category-droppable').droppable({
        tolerance: 'pointer',
        out: function (event, ui) {
            clearTimeout(globalTimer);
            if ($(this).attr('id') == 'level2') {
                $(this).find('ul:first').slideUp();
                $(this).find('span.glyphicon:first').toggleClass("glyphicon-chevron-right").toggleClass('glyphicon-chevron-down');
            }
        },
        over: function (event, ui) {
            console.log($(this).attr('id'));
            event.stopPropagation();
            $(this).find('ul:first').slideDown();
            if ($(this).attr('id') == 'level3') {
                if (!$(this).is(active)) {
                    current = $(this);
                    active.removeClass('list-group-item-info');
                    current.addClass('list-group-item-info');
                    globalTimer = setTimeout(function () {
                        current.addClass('active');
                        active.removeClass('active');
                        active = current;
                        if (showing) {
                            showing.hide()
                        }
                        load_category(current.html(), $('#' + current.attr('name')).find("ul:first"));
                        $('#' + current.attr('name')).show();
                        showing = $('#' + current.attr('name'));
                    }, 500);
                }
            } else if ($(this).attr('id') == 'level1' || $(this).attr('id') == 'level2') {
                $(this).find('span.glyphicon:first').toggleClass("glyphicon-chevron-right").toggleClass('glyphicon-chevron-down');
            }
        },
        drop: function (event, ui) {
            clearTimeout(globalTimer);
            if ($(this).attr('id') == 'level3') {
                update_category($(ui.draggable).attr('id'), $(this).html())
                $(ui.draggable).attr("style", "display: none");
                $(ui.draggable).detach().prependTo($('#' + $(this).attr('name')).children('ul'));
                $(ui.draggable).fadeIn();
                $(ui.draggable).draggable({
                    helper: 'clone',
                    appendTo: "body",
                    zIndex: 100,
                    refreshPositions: true,
                    revert: 'invalid',
                    start: function (event, ui) {
                        $(this).css('visibility','hidden');
                    },
                    stop: function (event, ui) {
                        $(this).css('visibility','visible');
                    }
                });

            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

So if anyone happens to have the same problem: 
Removing the clearTimeout(globalTimer); on droppable.out gives the desired functionality.

See the working fiddle here:

```
out: function(event, ui) {
  if ($(this).attr('id') == 'level2') {
    $(this).find('ul:first').slideUp();
    $(this).find('span.glyphicon:first').toggleClass("glyphicon-chevron-right").toggleClass('glyphicon-chevron-down');
```

https://jsfiddle.net/bkfxjnom/5/